# Hibernate Validator: Using constants in constraints.xml

Tags: hibernate-validator

I am using Hibernate Validator as a JSR-303 validation provider and its xml style constraints descriptions.
So, I have a

```
<bean class="com.my.User" ignore-annotations="true">
  <field name="email">
     <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Pattern">
         <element name="regexp"><![CDATA[[A-Za-z0-9\._%+-]{1,64}@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-  
                                   z]{2,4}]]></element>
     </constraint>
  </field>
  .....
</bean>
```

I also have a separate class, which contains all my patterns

```
public final class Regexps {
 public static final String EMAIL_REGEXP = "A-Za-z0-9\._%+-]{1,64}@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-  
                                 Za-z]{2,4}";
 ....
}
```

So, as you can see, I have two places, where email regexp is present, and I want only one place.

My question:
Is it possible to use the

```
public static final String EMAIL_REGEXP = "A-Za-z0-9\._%+-]{1,64}@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-   
                                           Za-z]{2,4}";
```

field inside the xml, so that

I could just refer to the contant string field.
So I would Like to have something like:

```
<bean class="com.my.User" ignore-annotations="true">
  <field name="email">
     <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Pattern">
         <element name="regexp">Regexps.EMAIL_REGEXP</element>
     </constraint>
  </field>
  .....
</bean>
```

By the way, it is possible via annotations

```
public class User {
 @Pattern(regexp = Regexps.EMAIL_REGEXP)   
 private String email;
}
```

But I cannot use annotations, because I use the legacy POJOs which I use for data transfering and cannot change the source code.

Comment: As reference https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-839

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to reference constraints from within XML constrained mappings. I think it's a good idea, though. Could you open a feature request in our [issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV) so we can discuss the feature there?

If you can't use annotations, you might give Hibernate Validator's [API for programmatic constraint declaration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api) a try, you could then work with a shared constant for the pattern.